# Update changed value of TextBox control of one instance of form into all instances

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a parent form and child forms (both are windows form). On the parent form I have a `TabControl` with 2 tabs and each tab I need to add a child form.

On one child form I have a `TextBox` with some value as initial value. All I want is when I changed the TextBox value on one of the instances of child form it needs to update the other instances as well.

I have managed to add two instances on the form,

```
Private Sub Parent_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ch As New Child
    Dim ch1 As New Child
    ch.Top = False
    ch.TopLevel = False
    ch1.Top = False
    ch1.TopLevel = False
    Panel1.Controls.Add(ch1)
    ch1.Show()
    Panel2.Controls.Add(ch)
    ch.Show()
End Sub
```

but don't know how to change value on other instance when changed on one instance.

Comment: *and each tab I need to add a child form* You want to add form on the tab?

Comment: @JohnyL TopLevel is false, turning a form into a UserControl, essentially.

Comment: @LarsTech Oops... Missed that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data-binding to application settings or data-binding to a single instance of any other class which supports two way data-binding:

1. Open *Settings.settings* file.
   *It's under My Project node in solution explorer if you choose to show all files from solution explorer toolbar. You can also open it by right clicking on project node, choosing Properties and selecting Settings tab.*
2. Add a new setting property and call it something, for example *Setting1* and let the type be string and assign a default value if you like.
3. Open you form(s) at designer.
4. Choose the `TextBox` in which you want to show the value.
5. In *Properties Window*, expand *(Application Settings)* and click on <kbd>...</kbd> in front of *(PropertyBinding)*.
6. In the *Application Settings* window, choose `Text` property and as value, choose the setting property which you created in step 2.
7. If you have more than one form in which you want to show the value, repeat step 3 to 6 for each form.

When you run the application, when you type in any of the `TextBox` controls which are bound to the setting value, all the bound text boxes will be updated immediately.

Comment: Only one thing, does it not work for other data type i.e. decimal (in settings)?

Comment: It probably depends to the property type. Binding to `Text` property in this case probably needs a string property if you want to use with designer support with settings file. But in general as mentioned in the first line the solution is *data-binding to a single instance of any other class which supports two way data-binding*, and property binding to application settings is an example. If it has any limitation, use a single instance object and setup data-binding manually.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what [Reza Aghaei described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54241483/7444103), applied *manually*.

A description of the procedure:

- Create a container for the Child Forms that will be used for *basic management* (adding/removing and disposing of the child Forms). Here, a `List(Of Form)` named **`ChildForms`**.
- Create a `DataSource`, here a `DataTable` (named **`BindingDataTable`**), used to provide a default value to the TextBoxes in the 2 different Child Forms
- Create a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) (named **`TextBoxBindings`**) that will provide the binding logic/support for the controls.
- Set the `DataSource` of the `BindingSource` to the DataTable to connect the Data.
- Add [Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Binding);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) to the TextBox controls of the Child Forms to connect their Text property to the shared data source.
- Add an Event Handler to the [Binding.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.parse?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Binding.Parse);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) event which will be used to  parse/validate the value of Text property of the TextBoxes when it's changed.
- Add the border-less Child Forms to the TabControl's TabPages.
- Make use of the `List(Of Form)` to remove the Child Forms from the TabControl when necessary.

---

```
Private ChildForms As List(Of Form)
Private TextBoxBindings As BindingSource
Private BindingDataTable As DataTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    BindingDataTable = New DataTable("TextSource")
    BindingDataTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TextValue", GetType(String)))
    Dim row As DataRow = BindingDataTable.NewRow()
    row.ItemArray = New String() {"Default text"}
    BindingDataTable.Rows.Add(row)

    TextBoxBindings = New BindingSource()
    TextBoxBindings.DataSource = BindingDataTable

    ChildForms = New List(Of Form)
    Dim ch1, ch2 As New ChildForm With {
        .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
        .Location = Point.Empty,
        .Size = TabPage1.Size,
        .TopLevel = False
    }

    ChildForms.AddRange({ch1, ch2})

    For Each frm As Form In ChildForms
        Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(frm.Controls.Find("TextBox1", False)(0), TextBox)
        Dim txtBind = New Binding("Text", TextBoxBindings, "TextValue", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
        AddHandler txtBind.Parse, AddressOf Me.OnBindingParse
        txt.DataBindings.Add(txtBind)
    Next

    TabPage1.Controls.Add(ChildForms(0))
    TabPage2.Controls.Add(ChildForms(1))
    ChildForms.ForEach(Sub(f) f.Show())
End Sub

Friend Sub OnBindingParse(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs)
    If e.DesiredType Is GetType(String) Then
        TextBoxBindings.CurrencyManager.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnClearChilds_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClearChilds.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To ChildForms.Count - 1
        Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(ChildForms(i).Controls.Find("TextBox1", False)(0), TextBox)
        RemoveHandler txt.DataBindings.Item("Text").Parse, AddressOf Me.OnBindingParse
        ChildForms(i).Dispose()
    Next
    TextBoxBindings.Dispose()
    BindingDataTable.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Sample result:

[image: BindingSource to WinForms Controls]

Comment: Many Thanks for comment @Jimi. I used the Property Way as suggested by Reza Aghaei.as i have lots of controls (textboxes) that needs updating :-)